# How to keep the mobile menu open when loaded for the first time Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, mobile-menu

I want to keep the **mobile menu open** when the website is loaded for the first time magento2. After that, it should work as the default on open close by click. Can anyone suggest to me?
[image]

Comment: Do you mean that sleeping & livings, brands should be open for first time.?

Comment: Yes, These should be expandable on first load.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using jQuery, try the below code in the `toggle` function of the `menu.js` file.
Override this file to your theme or you can extend it also.

File: `lib/web/mage/menu.js`

Code to add in function:

```
$('.level0.parent > a').each(function(){
    if (!$(this).hasClass('_ignoreTrigger')) {
        $(this).addClass('ui-state-active');
        $(this).next().show();
        $(this).addClass('_ignoreTrigger');
    }
});
```

Toggle function will look like this:

```
toggle: function () {
    var html = $('html');

    if (html.hasClass('nav-open')) {
        html.removeClass('nav-open');
        setTimeout(function () {
            html.removeClass('nav-before-open');
        }, this.options.hideDelay);
    } else {
        html.addClass('nav-before-open');
        setTimeout(function () {
            html.addClass('nav-open');
            /** Auto open submenus for first time **/
            $('.level0.parent > a').each(function(){
                if (!$(this).hasClass('_ignoreTrigger')) {
                    $(this).addClass('ui-state-active');
                    $(this).next().show();
                    $(this).addClass('_ignoreTrigger');
                }
            });
            /** END **/
        }, this.options.showDelay);
    }
},
```

Comment: It opens the first time but when I click on the same link then again open it and not working properly.

Comment: Yes, it will open after each page load. but if you dont want to open it on each page load then you have to use cookies. So instead of addClass _ignoreTrigger, you can set cookie there and then check the cookie and if cookie not set then show submenus.

Comment: Yes, maybe it will work. I will try this and let you know if work.

Comment: Yeah sure. If my answer is helpful to you then mark it as accepted and upvote. Thank you,